# Is there a way to link some sheet data when this sheet was copied to the new one?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm building an addon to Google Sheets that shows some information into a sheet and saves data to the Document storage by `PropertiesService`. I know there is no way to check when a sheet was copied if I want to copy/link the data with the new sheet. And I heard and read about `DeveloperMetadata`. But didn't realize: is `DeveloperMetadata` per Sheet copies when the source sheet copies to the new one? I tried and saw, that no.

So, is it right? If "yes", is there no difference between using `PropertiesService` per Document and `DeveloperMetadata` per Sheet in this case?

**UPD:** (about `DeveloperMetadata`)

I created a new spreadsheet and wrote to the Script Editor 2 functions:

```js
function showAllMetadata()
{
  var allSheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  var allDeveloperMetadata = allSheets.map(function(sheet){
    return {
      id:       sheet.getSheetId(),
      name:     sheet.getName(),
      metadata: sheet.getDeveloperMetadata().map(function(meta){ return meta.getValue() })
    }
  });
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(allDeveloperMetadata));
}

function addMetadataToCurrentSheet()
{
  SpreadsheetApp
    .getActiveSheet()
    .addDeveloperMetadata('metadata', 'foo');
  showAllMetadata();
}
```

Then I made:

1. Run `addMetadataToCurrentSheet()` and saw

```
[{"id":0,"name":"Sheet1","metadata":["foo"]}]
```

2. Duplicated this sheet by clicking on the "Duplicate" button
3. Run `showAllMetadata()` and saw

```
[
  {"id":0,"name":"Sheet1","metadata":["foo"]},
  {"id":1107155653,"name":"Copy of Sheet1","metadata":[]}
]
```

But I expected to see

```
[
  {"id":0,"name":"Sheet1","metadata":["foo"]},
  {"id":1107155653,"name":"Copy of Sheet1","metadata":["foo"]}
]
```

Comment: Does the sheet data has to be specifically linked to that `sheet`? It cannot be attached to the `spreadsheet`? Because if it can be attached to the `spreadsheet`, a copied `spreadsheet` keeps the `DeveloperMetadata` you added to the original one. Also, I assume you want to copy to another `spreadsheet`? Because if the `sheet` is copied to the same original `spreadsheet` (via creating a `Duplicate`), the `DeveloperMetadata` is also kept. Can you clarify on all this?

Comment: @Iamblichus, updated. Attaching to the sheet metadata is the best choice. It would allow getting rid of the trash in storage if a sheet was removed. But will I see a different behavior if will use `spreadsheet developer metadata`, don't you know?

Comment: Checked now: if I use `sheet developer metadata` and copy a spreadsheet then in this copy I'll have the same metadata as in the source spreadsheet. Also if I use "Copy to" button metadata exists too in the copy. It seems that the "Duplicate" button doesn't copy metadata.

Comment: You're right. Sorry, I got confused. A `sheet` copied via [copyTo](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#copytospreadsheet) keeps the metadata, as well as one copied via the `Copy to` button. Copying the full spreadsheet works too. So I guess your issue is now solved? `DeveloperMetadata` connected to a sheet can be linked to a copy of the sheet. Please consider posting an answer summarizing all this, as this can be useful for other users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarize received information:

`DeveloperMetadata` per sheet connects a sheet with its storage and if we want to copy this sheet with its metadata and do:

1. Copy a spreadsheet - metadata exists
2. Copy a sheet via `Copy to` button or via `copyTo` method - metadata exists
3. Copy a sheet via `Duplicate` button - metadata doesn't exist

Hope, `Duplicate` button will work correctly in the future.